# Which 'asset' syntex is appropriate to include js and css files?

Tags: php, laravel

I have tested both 'asset' structures and both works perfectly. Structure 2 is much easier to use rather than the 2nd one. However i would like to know which structure is standard and if i use structure 2 will there occur any future error or problem? I want to use structure 2 only for js and css asseting.

**Structure 1:**

```
href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"
```

**Structure 2:**

```php
href="{{ asset('/') }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more future compatibility I'll go for 1:

```
href="{{asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
href="{{URL::asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first structure is the basic structure used in the laravel docs. So it's the best to use i think.

The second didn't link your files, it's only link the public repository, that's not really usefull.

I think the 1 is better, but you can use both. Just use the same method in all your application and it's will be fine.